# Como desenhar pontos entre uma imagem e outra com HTML5 e CSS3?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Tenho ícones, separados em divs, e o layout original tem estes pontinhos. Tentei utilizar imagens, mas desconfigura meu layout.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como colocar estes pontos entre as imagens?

Comment: Usa uma imagem que é um ponto e repete ela verticalmente como background em uma div no meio dessas imagens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma alternativa é usar o `border style dotted` e ir intercalando a cada imagem, também é necessário um container para centralizar os elementos, exemplo...

```css
.containerImgs {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.pontilhado{
  border-left-style: dotted;
  border-left-width: 4px;
  border-left-color:#53fd34;
  height: 70px;
  width: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="containerImgs">

  <img src="https://fakeimg.pl/100/">
  <div class="pontilhado"></div>

  <img src="https://fakeimg.pl/100/">
  <div class="pontilhado"></div> 

  <img src="https://fakeimg.pl/100/">

</div>
```

Referências 
[Border Style](https://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/pr_border-style.asp)

[Flexbox guia completo](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: deu certo! Obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Uma outra forma de implementar é utilizar o elemento `hr` verticalmente através de uma classe.

```css
.container {
  text-align: center;
}

.vertical-dotted-hr {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  border: none;
  border-top: 5px dotted;
  color: rgb(244, 128, 36);
}

img {
  width: 30%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

<img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png?v=73d79a89bded"/>
  <hr class="vertical-dotted-hr" />
<img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png?v=73d79a89bded"/>

</div>
```